# Configure sub-domains at different ports with lighttpd

Tags: virtualhost, subdomain, lighttpd, http-proxy

I've one domain `example.com` and two sub domains of it `docs.example.com` & `bugs.example.com`. And I've two applications running at ports `8080` & `8090`. How to configure Lighttpd so that, it can forward all the requests at `docs.example.com` to `8090` and `bugs.example.com` to `8080`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have enabled `mod_proxy` in lighttpd. Paste this at the end of the configuration file and restart lighttpd.

```
$HTTP["host"] == "docs.example.com"
{   
   proxy.server = (
     "" => (
       "host" => (
         "host" => "127.0.0.1",
         "port" => 8080
       )
     )
   ) 
}
```

I'm not really sure if you'd be needing the `"host" => 127.0.0.1` line. It depends on how you are running the server on your machine.